# Similar to energy estimate in PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $B_1(0)$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$ centered at the origin. Assume that the function $v$ is a smooth function defined on $\mathbb R^3$ with $v_r = \frac{x\cdot\nabla v}{|x|}\in L^2(B_1(0))$. Prove that
$$\begin{align*}\int_{B_1(0)}\frac{|v(x)|^2}{|x|^2}dx & \le C(\int_{B_1(0)}|v_r|^2dx+\int_{\partial B_1(0)}|v|^2d\sigma)\\ &\le C_1\int_{B_1(0)}(|v_r|^2+|v|^2)dx\end{align*}$$
where $C$ and $C_1$ are some constants independent of $v$.

The righthand side is very similar to energy estimate in PDE, and common ways of dealing energy estimate in PDE includes multiplying a same term and integrate. But there's no PDE here and the LHS is not common and I have no idea how to construct the $\frac{|v(x)|^2}{|x|^2}$, still I believe that this problem SHOULD be solved by PDE energy estimates. Is there a way of using energy estimates here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use that $$\nabla \bigg ( \frac 1 {\vert x \vert}\bigg ) = -\frac x{\vert x\vert^{3}}$$ to write $$ \frac 1{\vert x\vert^2}= -\nabla \bigg ( \frac 1 {\vert x \vert}\bigg )  \cdot \frac x {\vert x\vert} $$ then integrate by parts.